# Suggested edit by an anonymous user?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was checking the edit queue when I saw a post with a suggested edit.  In the corner it said:

> proposed 8 mins ago by an anonymous user

Does this just mean a non-logged in user has made an edit...?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that's from a non logged in user.

For tons more reading and everything you'd ever want to know about suggested edits:

> [Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 10 minutes old. These edits are attributed to the Community user upon approval.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/193412)

Comment: Ah, thanks!  So as I thought, I am indeed an idiot :)

Comment: @JaneS Not an idiot at all! Just learning the ropes, and rather quickly might I add! :)

Comment: @DavidK Thanks!  I just try to apply common sense and experience. Although my experience is that common sense isn't that common! ;)